Interpret smd values from gt_summary
I am using add_difference() to obtain SMDs for various epidemiological variables in an exploratory study with two groups, therefore no hypothesis driven chi-square comparisons. I would rather rely on SMDs to evaluate group differences.
Can you recommend cut-offs/interpretations for when SMDs are considered large or small/meaningful? ChatGPT had a few suggestions and the Cohen's d-like cut-offs seem to apply as well. But maybe I am missing something.
